# NODE JS - Can you tell me what I am doing wrong with the directory order?

Tags: node.js

I am super new to Node JS and I was able to run this js file before. Right now, I can't and I don't know why. It says that it doesn't see app.js file under the config folder but as you see there is app.js under the config and I also gave direction in server.js. Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: I can't read anything in that image.

Answer (score 0):

if you are importing app.js file its a good idea to add .js at the end just like this

```
var app = require('../server/config/app.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `..` when your server.js file is at the same level as the `server` directory. Use one `.` and it should work

```js
const app = require('./server/config/app');
```